# How do I test for dictionary<int,int> with no value

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
public static Dictionary<int,int> IdToDbIdMap
{
    get => (Dictionary<int, int>Cx.FixedData[nameof(Cx0.IdToDbIdMap)];
    set => Cx.SetFixed(nameof(Cx0.IdToDbIdMap), value);
}
```

The issue I have is that if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary, then it crashes with `'keyNotFound'` exception. How can I change the above to return 0 if not found.

Comment: [Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryGetValue(TKey, TValue) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Your `get` can't return 0. I suppose it could return a `Dictionary<int, int>` that has a key and value of 0, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Hi @JimMischel returning dictionary<0,0> would work for me, but Im having difficulty changing the getter on, this. It's someone elses code that I've had to pick up. I've tried forcing a TryGetValue onto the call, but no luck

Comment: @bilpor We could help more if you could provide a [mcve].